# Flutter raster crash: recursive_mutex unlock crash in FontStyle::registerLanguageList

Tags: sdk, flutter

Recently, Many uses of my app crash, The stack tells me something like multi-threads sync goes wrong. Does anybody know the reason?

My flutter SDK version is Flutter 1.17.5 • channel stable, and the flutter doctor results are

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale zh-Hans-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)

```
    [✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Here is the complete stack trace details of crashed thread below:

```
    Thread 13 name: io.flutter.1.ui Thread 13 Crashed:
    0 libsystem_kernel.dylib ___pthread_kill (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) 8
    1 libsystem_c.dylib _abort (in libsystem_c.dylib) 140
    2 libc++abi.dylib ___cxa_bad_cast (in libc++abi.dylib) 0
    3 libc++abi.dylib default_terminate_handler() (in libc++abi.dylib) 284
    4 libobjc.A.dylib _objc_terminate() (in libobjc.A.dylib) 140
    5 libc++abi.dylib std::__terminate(void ()()) (in libc++abi.dylib) 16
    6 libc++abi.dylib ___cxa_get_exception_ptr (in libc++abi.dylib) 0
    7 libc++abi.dylib __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception) (in libc++abi.dylib) 0
    8 libc++.1.dylib std::__1::__throw_system_error(int, char const*) (in libc++.1.dylib) 88
    9 libc++.1.dylib std::__1::recursive_mutex::unlock() (in libc++.1.dylib) 0
    10 Flutter minikin::FontStyle::registerLanguageList(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&) (in Flutter) (mutex:499) 12
    11 Flutter txt::(anonymous namespace)::GetMinikinFontStyle(txt::TextStyle const&) (in Flutter) (paragraph_txt.cc:145) 0
    12 Flutter xt::(anonymous namespace)::GetFontAndMinikinPaint(txt::TextStyle const&, minikin::FontStyle*, minikin::MinikinPaint*) (in Flutter) (paragraph_txt.cc:155) 4
    13 Flutter txt::ParagraphTxt::Layout(double) (in Flutter) (paragraph_txt.cc:311) 16
    14 Flutter flutter::Paragraph_layout(_Dart_NativeArguments*) (in Flutter) 108
    15 Flutter dart::NativeEntry::AutoScopeNativeCallWrapperNoStackCheck(_Dart_NativeArguments*, void ()(_Dart_NativeArguments)) (in Flutter) (native_entry.cc:215) 8
    16 App Precompiled_Stub_CallAutoScopeNative (in App) 72
    17 App Precompiled_Paragraph__layout_16065589_1659 (in App) 60
    18 App Precompiled_Paragraph_layout_10357 (in App) 40
    19 App Precompiled_TextPainter_layout_10753 (in App) 740
    20 App Precompiled_RenderParagraph__layoutText_509149678_4671 (in App) 316
    21 App Precompiled_RenderParagraph__layoutTextWithConstraints_509149678_4665 (in App) 92
    22 App Precompiled_RenderParagraph_performLayout_10469 (in App) 132
    23 App Precompiled_RenderObject_layout_10739 (in App) 1140
    24 App Precompiled_RenderConstrainedBox_performLayout_10491 (in App) 172
    25 App Precompiled_RenderObject_layout_10739 (in App) 1140
    26 App Precompiled_RenderFlex_performLayout_10516 (in App) 1164
    27 App Precompiled_RenderObject_layout_10739 (in App) 1140
    28 App Precompiled_RenderConstrainedBox_performLayout_10491 (in App) 172
    29 App Precompiled_RenderObject_layout_10739 (in App) 1140
    30 App Precompiled_RenderFlex_performLayout_10516 (in App) 1164
    31 App Precompiled_RenderObject_layout_10739 (in App) 1140
    32 App Precompiled_RenderPadding_performLayout_10489 (in App) 384
    33 App Precompiled_RenderObject_layout_10739 (in App) 1140
    34 App Precompiled_RenderConstrainedBox_performLayout_10491 (in App) 172
    35 App Precompiled_RenderObject_layout_10739 (in App) 1140
    36 App Precompiled_RenderFlex_performLayout_10516 (in App) 1164
    37 App Precompiled_RenderObject_layout_10739 (in App) 1140
    38 App Precompiled__RenderProxyBox_RenderBox_RenderObjectWithChildMixin_RenderProxyBoxMixin_795160605_performLayout_10500 (in App) 144
    39 App Precompiled_RenderObject_layout_10739 (in App) 1140
    40 App Precompiled__RenderProxyBox_RenderBox_RenderObjectWithChildMixin_RenderProxyBoxMixin_795160605_performLayout_10500 (in App) 144
    41 App Precompiled_RenderObject_layout_10739 (in App) 1140
    42 App Precompiled__RenderProxyBox_RenderBox_RenderObjectWithChildMixin_RenderProxyBoxMixin_795160605_performLayout_10500 (in App) 144 43 App Precompiled_RenderObject_layout_10739 (in App) 1140
    44 App Precompiled_RenderFlex_performLayout_10516 (in App) 1164
    45 App Precompiled_RenderObject__layoutWithoutResize_792266271_2092 (in App) 52
    46 App Precompiled_PipelineOwner_flushLayout_2049 (in App) 536
    47 App Precompiled__WidgetsFlutterBinding_BindingBase_GestureBinding_ServicesBinding_SchedulerBinding_PaintingBinding_SemanticsBinding_RendererBinding_24399801_drawFrame_3099 (in App) 48
    48 App Precompiled__WidgetsFlutterBinding_BindingBase_GestureBinding_ServicesBinding_SchedulerBinding_PaintingBinding_SemanticsBinding_RendererBinding_WidgetsBinding_24399801_drawFrame_3203 (in App) 232
    49 App Precompiled__WidgetsFlutterBinding_BindingBase_GestureBinding_ServicesBinding_SchedulerBinding_PaintingBinding_SemanticsBinding_RendererBinding_24399801__handlePersistentFrameCallback_779452173_3103 (in App) 32
    50 App Precompiled__WidgetsFlutterBinding_BindingBase_GestureBinding_ServicesBinding_SchedulerBinding_PaintingBinding_SemanticsBinding_RendererBinding_24399801__handlePersistentFrameCallback_779452173__handlePersistentFrameCallback_779452173_3090 (in App) 188
    51 App Precompiled__WidgetsFlutterBinding_BindingBase_GestureBinding_ServicesBinding_SchedulerBinding_24399801__invokeFrameCallback_815222615_3261 (in App) 144
    52 App Precompiled__WidgetsFlutterBinding_BindingBase_GestureBinding_ServicesBinding_SchedulerBinding_24399801_handleDrawFrame_3218 (in App) 296
    53 App Precompiled__WidgetsFlutterBinding_BindingBase_GestureBinding_ServicesBinding_SchedulerBinding_24399801__handleDrawFrame_815222615_3238 (in App) 72
    54 App Precompiled__WidgetsFlutterBinding_BindingBase_GestureBinding_ServicesBinding_SchedulerBinding_24399801__handleDrawFrame_815222615__handleDrawFrame_815222615_3224 (in App) 120
    55 App Precompiled_____rootRun_4048458_338 (in App) 232
    56 App Precompiled_____rootRun_4048458__rootRun_4048458_339 (in App) 504
    57 App Precompiled__CustomZone_4048458_run_18351 (in App) 240
    58 App Precompiled__CustomZone_4048458_runGuarded_18453 (in App) 52
    59 App Precompiled_____invoke_16065589_1362 (in App) 184
    60 App Precompiled_____drawFrame_16065589_1345 (in App) 176
    61 App Precompiled_Stub_InvokeDartCode (in App) 252
    62 Flutter dart::DartEntry::InvokeFunction(dart::Function const&, dart::Array const&, dart::Array const&, unsigned long) (in Flutter) (dart_entry.cc:190) 20
    63 Flutter Dart_Invoke (in Flutter) (object.cc:12299) 16
    64 Flutter flutter::Window::BeginFrame(fml::TimePoint) (in Flutter) 280
    65 Flutter std::__1::__function::__func<flutter::Animator::AwaitVSync()::$_3, std::__1::allocatorflutter::Animator::AwaitVSync()::$_3, void (fml::TimePoint, fml::TimePoint)>::operator()(fml::TimePoint&&, fml::TimePoint&&) (in Flutter) (animator.cc:142) 20
    66 Flutter std::__1::function<void (fml::TimePoint, fml::TimePoint)>::operator()(fml::TimePoint, fml::TimePoint) const (in Flutter) 44
    67 Flutter fml::MessageLoopImpl::FlushTasks(fml::FlushType) (in Flutter) 1960
    68 Flutter fml::MessageLoopDarwin::OnTimerFire(__CFRunLoopTimer*, fml::MessageLoopDarwin*) (in Flutter) 32
    69 CoreFoundation _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION (in CoreFoundation) 28
    70 CoreFoundation ___CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation) 864
    71 CoreFoundation ___CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation) 248 0�Thread 14 name: io.flutter.1.raster
```